# Avoid NSDocument from reopening from Trash

Tags: swift, macos, nsdocument, recycle-bin

Working on a NSDocument-based app, I discovered that if I delete a file (package) from the filesystem, the app will still try to reopen it—from the trash.

Even if this succeeded it would be confusing. Currently I have a crude check in `applicationOpenUntitledFile` for `url.path.contains(".Trash")`.

There must be a better way to avoid reopening trashed documents! What is it?

Comment: What macOS are you trying this on?  It's curious because in my experience I haven't had a problem with this.

Comment: This is macOS Sierra. And I see I wrote "reopen", what I meant is "restore".